# Pandas float16 conversion

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to optimise my df dtypes to consume less memory.

I came out with the following solution for floats:

```
@staticmethod
def optimize_float(series):
    low_consumption = series.astype('float16')
    if any(low_consumption.isin([np.inf])):
        medium_consumption = series.astype('float32')
        if any(medium_consumption.isin([np.inf])):
            return series.astype('float64')
        return medium_consumption
    return low_consumption
```

I came across a weird use case as follows:

```
In[89]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[11111,22222,3333]})
In[90]: df
Out[90]: 
       a
0  11111
1  22222
2   3333
In[91]: df.astype('float16')
Out[91]: 
         a
0  11112.0
1  22224.0
2   3332.0
In[92]: df.astype('float32')
Out[92]: 
         a
0  11111.0
1  22222.0
2   3333.0
```

when converting to `float16` it rounded up\changed the values in my series, while I expected it to put `inf` or throw an error if it cant convert that to the dtype I passed through.

I also noticed differences in the describe() method output on that df:

```
In[83]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[11111,22222,3333]})
In[84]: df['a'].describe()
Out[84]: 
count        3.000000
mean     12222.000000
std       9493.383011
min       3333.000000
25%       7222.000000
50%      11111.000000
75%      16666.500000
max      22222.000000
Name: a, dtype: float64
In[85]: df['a'].astype('float16').describe()
Out[85]: 
count    3.000000e+00
mean     1.222400e+04
std               inf
min      3.332000e+03
25%      7.222000e+03
50%      1.111200e+04
75%      1.666800e+04
max      2.222400e+04
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

How can I convert my series to the lowest consuming memory type without loosing\altering any data?

where did my logic in the `optimize_float` function fails?

Comment: a long time later i'm here to ask you, you managed to solve this problem, i'm trying to solve a very similar problem.